# Python wireless transfers with SonyQX1

Tags: python, http, urllib, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm currently using the sony QX1 for wireless transfers for large images. The camera is being triggered over the USB port. Pictures from the camera are being transferred with URLLib to a raspberry pi. (I can't use the api to trigger the camera. It has to be from this external source.)

The camera is triggered around every 2.5 seconds. Through timing testing it seems like I'm able to get the larger picture back to the pi at ~ 3.2 seconds per image.

I've noticed that when the camera is triggered my transfer is terminated. I'm assuming this has to do with the embedded design of the camera itself and there isn't a way to get around this but please correct me if I'm wrong!

Does the camera support the range header? Basically I grab the image size from the header. I'm trying to grab the beginning X bytes until the camera triggers again then grab the next X bytes until I get the entire image.

Thanks for the help and let me know if I need to give a deeper explanation of what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the range header, but it will still not allow you to take more pictures than your downloadspeed allows (unless you have some larger than 2.5 seconds intervals now and then). 
Maybe you can reduce the image resolution to a size that fits into the 2.5 sec interval? Or (just some thinking outside of the box:-) use 2 QX1's switching, so you get a 5 second interval for each...

Comment: You can take more pictures than your download speed allows if you're not directly saving the image from the camera to your device. Unfortunately I need the pictures to be large and I can't use a second camera due to space/weight requirements. I've since finished the project but the standard range header was not accepted. Thanks for the thoughts!